# SFX on collision

Tags: game-engine

I am making a game which has collectible items in it. I want to have a sound effect play when it is collected, but it won't play (I'm using logic bricks, since I have no experience with Python). I have it set up like this:
Collision (Property: Player)
And An 1
Edit Object: End Object
+
Sound (Ex. Sonic Ring Sound): Play Stop
Volume 2.00 Pitch 0.00

I also have background music set up through an empty cube with 2.00 volume, but im sure that wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Pleas add at least a screenshot of relevant bricks setup (use editor tool, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post?)

Comment: Sorry, I have fixed the problem. I'll make sure to next time I have a question.

Comment: So, you could an answer yourself, and later accept it, to explain how you solved, to help other users...

Comment: Someone actually programmed it in for me, since they have made blender games for a while.

Comment: They had the bricks set up to if both the x button and left/right were pressed the camera would rotate -10/10 degrees, respectively, along with the character.